# Protractor: Not able to validate two arrays using map from Protractor api

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am having hard time to find a way to deal with an array that gets returned by the protractor in unusual format. After I try to read a data table (using .map()). The array look like this that gets returned:

```
[ '', ' ', 'Automation_1', 'Car is one of
Sedan', 'http://www.goolge.com', '123', 'Query Params
No
Relative Option
None', 'Always', 'Never', '' ]
```

Here is the array with which I am trying to compare:

```
[ '', ' ', 'Automation_1', 'Car is one of Sedan', 'http://www.yahoo.com', '123', 'Query Params No Redirect Option None', 'Always', 'Never', '' ]
```

And Here is my code

```
var row = element(by.repeater('row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)').row(i));
var cells = row.all(by.tagName('td'));
var cellTexts = cells.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
}); expect(cellTexts).toEqual([ '', ' ', 'Automation_1', 'Car is one of Sedan', 'http://www.yahoo.com', '123', 'Query Params No Redirect Option None', 'Always', 'Never', '' ]);
```

Please let me know how to tackle the array that i am getting back so that I can successfully compare it.

Comment: How does it fail now? What do you see on the console?

Comment: @alecxe Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation

Comment: @alecxe Data present in the column is not in one line. There is a text and there are few sub texts below it with bullet points. But for some reason when I do `var cells = row.all(by.tagName('td'));
var cellTexts = cells.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();`
it captures the data literally and add whitespace to create same structure. As you see in the first array that I posted. The structure/format of the two arrays are different although content is same.

Comment: @alecxe Do you have any solution for this.??